# Example of dense set in space of integers

Tags: general-topology

Let X be the space of integers where topology T is class of sets $\emptyset, \{1\}, \{1,2\}, \{1,2,3\},\{1,2,3,4\} \cdots, X$. Is it correct that each open set except $\emptyset$ is dense in space of integers in this topology.

I think, closure of any set which contains 1 would be X, so any such set would be a dense set in this space.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's right. In fact, it's not hard to show:

> A set $A$ of integers (in your topology) is dense iff $1\in A$.

Comment: Quite clear from: "$D$ is dense iff for every non-empty open set $O$, $O \cap D \neq \emptyset$". And $1 \in \cap_{O \neq \emptyset, O \in \tau} O$.